# Why is a flask app.route causing a class method to loop?

Tags: python, flask

I have a HTML Page with multiple divs containing links. When I click on the link, flask should run the class method and then render that same page again.

```py
@app.route("/<drinkName>/")
def action(drinkName:str):
    goodDrinks = initBartender(drink_list)
    for drink in goodDrinks:
        drink:MenuItem
        if drink.name == drinkName:    
            Bartender().makeDrink(drink, drink.attributes['ingredients'])
    return render_template('./index.html')
```

```py
def makeDrink(self, drink:MenuItem, ingredients: dict[str, int]):
        self.running = True
        print('Making your drink...')
        maxTime = 0
        pumpThreads = []
        for ing in ingredients.keys():
            for pump in self.pump_configuration.keys():
                if ing == self.pump_configuration[pump]['value']:
                    waitTime = ingredients[ing] * FLOW_RATE
                    if waitTime > maxTime:
                        maxTime = waitTime
                    pump_t = threading.Thread(target=self.pour, args=(self.pump_configuration[pump]['pin'], waitTime))
                    pumpThreads.append(pump_t)
        print(f"Making {drink.name}!")

        for thread in pumpThreads:
            thread:threading.Thread
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
        self.running = False
```

I tried swapping the return render template for a redirect to the base url, I tried indenting the render_template to directly below the class method. This is my console log.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:46:07] "GET /Screwdriver HTTP/1.1" 308 -
Making your drink...
Making Screwdriver!
Making your drink...
Making Screwdriver!
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:50:07] "GET /Screwdriver/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:50:08] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:50:08] "GET /static/drinkList.json HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

As you can see, it runs the class method twice and takes four minutes to render index.html. I want to make it so that it runs the class method once, then (with as little delay as possible) render index.html

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two `Screwdriver`s in your `goodDrinks` list?

Comment: @AKX I changed the code slightly - i put in a print(drink.name) just before if drink.name = drinkName, and i get this
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 10:20:11] "GET /Gin%20&%20Tonic HTTP/1.1" 308 -
Rum & Coke
Gin & Tonic
Making your drink...
Making Gin & Tonic!
Long Island
Screwdriver
Margarita
Gin & Juice
Tequila Sunrise
Rum & Coke
Gin & Tonic
Making your drink...
Making Gin & Tonic!
this repeats several more times, then i get 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 10:34:11] "GET /Gin%20%26%20Tonic/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -. i now think that the app.route is being called multiple times